# Fast way to find a unhappy number

Tags: c++, math, numbers, combinations, number-theory

I'm trying to solve a question. Given a range of integers user has to find the number of unhappy present in the given range.

[Unhappy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Unhappy_number)- a number n such that iterating this sum-of-squared-digits map starting with n never reaches the number 1.

I've tried using the brute force approach by calculating the sum of the squares of digits and if at any instant it is equal to any of these (4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20) then it is a unhappy number.

This approach is giving TLE is there any better method??

Range is between 1 to 10^18.

Comment: SO users, please don't downvote the question just because you can't answer it!

Comment: Please add the brute force code that you have tried

Comment: @CrakC Couldn't have said it better my self. Just because someone has never heard of a happy number or an unhappy number they downvote and leave, very annoying.

Comment: The wikipedia entry for Happy numbers lists programmatic ways of determining if a number is happy or unhappy:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Unhappy_number

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw the link is on the question.

Comment: @gsamaras I was the one who put it there lol. Look at the edit history

Comment: @gsamaras I put it there because when I got here the question had a score of -2 because everyone was downvoting because they had never heard of unhappy numbers, so I linked to it so that they would know it's a real thing.

Comment: I am not so sure about that @AlbertRenshaw. But anyway, the question got two answers. :)

Comment: @gsamaras http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33324209/revisions <<<

Comment: Oh I misread your comment. Good move @AlbertRenshaw.

Answer (score 4):

Your range is between 1 and 10<sup>18</sup>. This means your numbers have a maximum of 18 digits.

Consider that the maximum square of a digit is 9<sup>2</sup> = 81, after doing the squared-digit-sum once the maximum number is 18 * 81 = 1458.

So one squared-digit-sum plus a lookup table of ~1500 elements should suffice.

Or two squared-digit-sums plus a lookup table of ~330 elements:

```
static const bool unhappy[330] {
    1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
    0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,
    1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0
}

inline bool is_unhappy(uint64_t n) {
    while (n >= 330) {
        int r = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            int d = n % 10;
            r += d*d;
            n /= 10;
        }
        n = r;
    }

    return unhappy[n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <set>

bool happy(int number) {
    static std::map<int, bool> cache;

    std::set<int> cycle;
    while (number != 1 && !cycle.count(number)) {
        if (cache.count(number)) {
            number = cache[number] ? 1 : 0;
            break;
        }
        cycle.insert(number);
        int newnumber = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            int digit = number % 10;
            newnumber += digit * digit;
            number /= 10;
        }
        number = newnumber;
    }
    bool happiness = number == 1;
    for (std::set<int>::const_iterator it = cycle.begin();
    it != cycle.end(); it++)
    cache[*it] = happiness;
    return happiness;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      if (!happy(i))
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
```

Logic and most of the code taken from here: https://tfetimes.com/c-happy-numbers/